# Action call lost with no exception thrown when calling a control's method from a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have this strange situation where I'm trying to call a control's method from
a thread. It's very simple code but for some reason, the call never gets executed if InvokeRequired is true. It hangs forever with no exception thrown.
Below is a simplified version and it also hangs once the control is added to a parent form. If it was not added to a form InvokeRequired is false and it works fine.

```
MyControl _ctl;
Thread _thread;

void Main()
{
    _ctl = new MyControl
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    };
    Form frm = new Form();
    frm.Controls.Add(_ctl);
    frm.Show();
    (_thread = new Thread(Test)).Start();
    //Thread.Sleep(2000);
    _thread.Join();
}

void Test()
{
    _ctl.Write("Hello...!");
}

class MyControl : TextBox
{
    int _inputStart = -1;

    public void Write(string value)
    {
        Action act = () =>
        {
            AppendText(value);
            _inputStart = SelectionStart;
        };

        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(act, Array.Empty<object>()); // this is where line execution hangs 
        else
            act();
    }
}
```

**I'd like to understand why does it hang? and what is the correct way to implement such scenario?**

**EDIT:**
OK, I made another sample code to run as a WinForm small app in response to comments of @Sami Kuhmonen

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testThreads
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
        private MyControl _ctl;
        private Button _button;
        private Thread _thread;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                components?.Dispose();
                components = null;
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void TestThreading()
        {
            (_thread = new Thread(Test)).Start();
            _thread.Join();
        }

        void Test()
        {
            _ctl.Write("Hello...!");
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            SuspendLayout();
            //
            // _ctl
            //
            _ctl = new MyControl
            {
                Multiline = true,
                Location = Point.Empty,
                Size = new Size(300, 175)
            };
            Controls.Add(_ctl);
            //
            // _button
            //
            _button = new Button
            {
                Location = new Point(0, 177),
                Size = new Size(60, 21),
                Text = "Test"
            };
            Controls.Add(_button);
            _button.Click += (s, e) => TestThreading();
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            ClientSize = new Size(300, 200);
            Name = "Form1";
            Text = "Form1";
            ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    }

    class MyControl : TextBox
    {
        int _inputStart = -1;

        public void Write(string value)
        {
            Action act = () =>
            {
                AppendText(value);
                _inputStart = SelectionStart;
            };

            if (InvokeRequired)
                Invoke(act, Array.Empty<object>());
            else
                act();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I don't use _thread.Join(); the code executes fine. But in my real scenario, I'm not using Thread.Join but waiting for a WaitHandle and it goes like this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testThreads
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
        private MyControl _ctl;
        private Button _button;
        private Thread _thread;
        private readonly AutoResetEvent _evt = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                components?.Dispose();
                components = null;
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void TestThreading()
        {
            (_thread = new Thread(Test)).Start();
            _evt.WaitOne();
        }

        void Test()
        {
            _ctl.Write("Hello...!");
            // simulate a long running task
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            _ctl.Write("Done");
            _evt.Set();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            SuspendLayout();
            //
            // _ctl
            //
            _ctl = new MyControl
            {
                Multiline = true,
                Location = Point.Empty,
                Size = new Size(300, 175)
            };
            Controls.Add(_ctl);
            //
            // _button
            //
            _button = new Button
            {
                Location = new Point(0, 177),
                Size = new Size(60, 21),
                Text = "Test"
            };
            Controls.Add(_button);
            _button.Click += (s, e) => TestThreading();
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            ClientSize = new Size(300, 200);
            Name = "Form1";
            Text = "Form1";
            ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    }

    class MyControl : TextBox
    {
        int _inputStart = -1;

        public void Write(string value)
        {
            Action act = () =>
            {
                AppendText(value);
                _inputStart = SelectionStart;
            };

            if (InvokeRequired)
                Invoke(act, Array.Empty<object>());// hangs
            else
                act();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this is a sample and it won't be a single thread.

**So I guess I need to block and wait until execution finishes while updating the control's UI. Or if there might be another non-blocking approach..**

Comment: Your UI thread is busy in sleep and joining the other thread so there’s no possibility for the invoke to run there.

Comment: No, If you removed the Thread.Sleep(...), still the same. When I debug, I can reach the line Invoke(act, Array.Empty<object>());. This is the line where execution discontinues.

Comment: And the join also? You must not have anything running on the main thread. Which of course is impossible in the way you’ve done this example since it will exit without it.

Comment: I never reach the line next to (_thread = new Thread(Test)).Start();

Comment: If you would like, you can give it a quick test using LINQPad

Comment: Make the application into a proper Windows Forms application with Application.Run() etc first.

Comment: I simplified the original code to the simplest form. I tested it on LINQPad to make sure the code behaves the same. If you omit the line Thread.Sleep(2000); and put a breakpoint on if (InvokeRequired) then press F10, You'll see that the form shows up and execution moves to the next line Invoke(act, Array.Empty<object>()); where it hangs.

Comment: You’ve simplified it too much. Please understand the basic things: if there’s no message loop running there can be no invokes. If the main thread is busy, no invokes can happen. So you need to make an actual test application which has a message loop and doesn’t hang the main thread in any sleeps, joins, or anything. Nothing.

Comment: OK, I'll try to make a new sample code to demonstrate the problem. I'll update shortly. Thanks

Comment: I see your point now, thanks for the hint. Please see the update

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thank you for the tip. I figured a better way to do it based on your hint. I made an async version of the Wait method also inspired by the DataFlow Complete and WaitForCompletion. I didn't realize I was blocking the UI thread at first.